# How to use DockerOperator from Airflow in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine

[from this example](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_docker_operator.py#L50-L56). `DockerOperator` has the `docker_url` parameter which is "URL of the host running the docker daemon.".

But when i run in Kubernetes engine on Google Cloud Platform, how can i find this `docker_url` on Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the following command to find out the docker url:

$docker-machine url [docker_machine_name]

Docker machine is not installed on the container images by default. You will have to install docker-machine manually by following these [steps](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/#install-machine-directly).

You will also have to use the Ubuntu image if you would like this functionality. I tried to install docker machine using a cos image, and it does not work since the image does not have the necessary dependencies.